# Need to boost the voltage and current from a digital output to drive a SSR

Tags: boost, solid-state-relay

The SSR needs 4 VDC at 8 mA. The digital output is 5V with 2.5 mA. Tried a Mikroe Boost 6 Click and it caused the relay to chatter. Tried an Adafruit PowerBoost 1000 and it loaded the digital output so it didn't feed the relay. I have researched several boost circuits and I Would like some help finding the correct type of boost for this.

Answer (score 2):

You can't get more power out than in.

4 VDC at 8 mA is 32 mW, 5 V at 2.5 mA is 12.5 mW. You're not going to convert 12.5 mW to 32 mW.

You don't need a different 'booster' you need to have the digital output switch a higher wattage supply, or a relay that takes less power.

Typically you would use the relatively low current digital output to drive a transistor, either bipolar or MOSFET, and have that switch power from a supply that can provide more current.

The way these boosters work is they trade voltage for current and vice-versa. If you have 5 V at 2 A, that's 10 W (Power = Voltage * Current). You can convert that to another voltage, either higher or lower, but you can't increase the power (it will actually be decreased because of inefficiency) so ignoring losses for now, if you needed 10 V the most current you could get is 1 A, if you wanted 2.5 V you could get 4 A. In the real world the output power available will be less that the input power, for 10 W in you might only get 9 W out. To in increase the power of a signal you need an amplifier, which relies on a power supply to provide the extra power, that's what you would be doing with a transistor buffer on the output.

Comment: Ok. I can look for a higher wattage supply.

Comment: @Cindest What do you have now? The 5 V @ 2.5 mA  digital output is coming out of some device, what is it, a microprocessor? What powers the device? What voltage and current is that rated at? The normal thing to do is use to use the low current output to switch voltage/current from the main supply using a transistor.

Comment: I knew that. I was hoping a boost converter would suffice.